# Add microdata to a Drupal site

Tags: drupal-7, microdata

Is there a way to add microdata to a Drupal 7 site by editing the field.tpl files? My site is built using panels and views so http://drupal.org/project/microdata isn't working. Is there another way to go about adding microdata by hard coding?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to add microdata is by editing the field.tpl files and then checking - use file templates on views. For panels I used the module http://drupal.org/project/panels_extra_styles to add coding around the pane.

Comment: I'm having trouble adding microdata to panel pages. Does anyone have an idea how to do it? I can't seem to add the schema code to wrap around the panel. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to override the page template file and wrap my panel in a code. 
The code I used was
template.php:

```
    function ThemeName_preprocess_page(&$vars) {

 // if this is a panel page, add template suggestions
if($panel_page = page_manager_get_current_page()) {
// add a generic suggestion for all panel pages
 $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__panel';
// add the panel page machine name to the template suggestions
$variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__' . $panel_page['name'];
$object = $panel_page['contexts']['argument_entity_id:node_1'];
$result_array = get_object_vars($object);
$value = $result_array['restrictions']['type']['0'];
    if($panel_page['name'] == 'node_view' AND $value == 'product' ) {
        $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__node_view_product';
    }
if($panel_page['name'] == 'node_view' AND $value == 'artist' ) {
        $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__node_view_artist';
    }
```

and I created a files under ThemeName/templates
page--node_view_artist.tpl.php and 
page--node_view_product.tpl.php

I hope this helps someone, it took me a long time to figure it out!